# Add multiple IDs to multiuser user textbox

Tags: sharepoint-online, multiple-values

I've a sharepoint list with a user field called "Account".

In a sharepoint page I've added a textbox bound to this field and I managed to set the value by inserting the `USERID` in the textbox.

Here is the texbox code:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="tbx_Account{$Pos}" Text="{@UserID}" Value="{@UserID}" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('tbx_Account',$Pos),'Text','TextChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Account')}"/>
```

In the same list I have another user field called `ProjectTeam`. Unlike the Account field, this is a multi-user field. I've tried to set multiple IDs separating them with comas `es. (3,47)` or with semicolon `es. (3;47)` but the save action results in an error.

Which is the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct format for multi-user fields is `ID;#LoginName;#ID;#LoginName`

So something like:

```
10;#contoso\kfrog;#23;#contoso\mpiggy;
```

You can find additional details and examples here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/uksharepoint/2009/02/17/quick-tip-using-the-sharepoint-person-or-group-field-in-code/

Comment: I've tried 10;#mpiggy@contoso.com;11;#kfrog@contoso.com --> NO WORK

Comment: I've tried 10;#mpiggy@contoso.com;11;#kfrog@contoso.com --> NO WORK; 10;#i:0#.f|membership|mpiggy@contoso.com;11;#i:0#.f|membership|tkfrog@contoso.com --> NO WORK and also 10;#|membership|mpiggy@contoso.com;11;#membership|tkfrog@contoso.com --> No WORK . In sharepoint online the login name is user@domain?

Comment: I left out a `#` above (sorry)! The values should be ID the LoginName, etc. The separator is `;#` between each.